# Deploying and validating in salesforce?

Tags: deployment

Instead of validating, If I do deployment straight away, Does the system validate and deploy if I select run all tests ?

Comment: Yes. Validating is useful to validate that your changeset has everything in it and passes the selected tests so you can deploy at a later time.

Comment: Yes, It validates all test methods and checks for code coverage and it runs successfully then it deploys the build

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as part of the deployment process using Change Sets it will run all the tests and require them to pass before the deployment is committed into the target Salesforce Org.

The value of validating prior to deployment is to highlight any issues with the Change Set and give you time to fix them before the changes may be required by the business.